# Hibernate collection with @ElementCollection contains duplicated elements in database

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Have a class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="sessions")
@Component
public class Session {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ElementCollection
    private Set<String> addedWords;
}
```

My flow is: get session one time. Add one word to `addedWords` and save session, repeat it. The problem that when I check my database, there are a lot of duplications, at the same time I don't have any duplications in Java class. So the `Set<String> addedWords` in class and this words in database not the same. Why I have this strange behavior and how to make things work well without any duplication? I use PostgreSQL. Saving method:

```
public synchronized void addWord(Session session, String word) {
        session.getAddedWords().add(word);
        sessionRepository.save(session);
}
```

Here spring config

```
spring:
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
```

Comment: You mean that when you try to add the same word to several `Session` entities and then persist them, you get duplicated word records in DB, right?

Comment: @SternK no, I add only different words to the Set, but somehow they are duplicate in database, for example in Set I have [a, b, c, d], in database is [a, a, b, b, c, c, d] for example. It happens after 1 saving, when it saves first time, there is no duplications, but then they appear...(when 2+ saving)

Comment: Could you please show how do you save it?

Comment: Please create and post a complete demo, doing all the adding, and saving to reproduce this issue.